# Why dialog box not open after click add reference in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-references-dialog

After clicking "add reference" in Visual Studio, dialog box does not open. 
Why? So I can't add any reference.

The screen just flashes like refresh but nothing appears after clicking "add reference". I need your help.
Thanks. I am a newbie in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Which programming language? What type of solution?

Comment: i use c# using visual studio 2010 .. I click add reference at solution explorer .. but nothing popup..

Comment: happenned to me that installed Add-on (dont remmember which) took over this dialog and prevent it to open, try disabling Add-ons, and check...

Comment: This might help - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/44c773bb-5003-44a1-9171-7b5302d8466b/vs2010-hangs-on-add-reference?forum=vseditor

Comment: try resetting your IDE settings > tools > import/export settings

Comment: Thank you all, i already solve that problem ..Close visual studio and stop service "Tablet PC input service" in task manager..

Answer (score 1):

Restart "TabletInputService" from services, and then don't forget to restart visual studio.